# Arguments from CSV as vector

Tags: r, csv, parsing, eval

I have a csv that contains my arguments for a function called eDMA.
One particular argument([vKeep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp7N0.jpg))takes the following values, either 1 or a vector of n items c(1,2).
I have tried the following but it doesn't work my way.

| auto |
| --- |
| c(1,2) |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| c(1,2) |

in

```
eval(parse(text=paste(auto[1,1])))
```

out

```
1 2
```

The output should have been c(1,2), any idea why?

Comment: Hi Sulz, and welcome to SO. Since this is about how `auto` is being parsed, I think adding data with `dput` to ensure this is fully reproducible could help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should make it clear that you are using the function `DMA` from the package `eDMA`. Instead of a picture, just refer to the manual page `?DMA`. It clearly states that the argument to `vKeep` must be a numeric vector. Your object `auto` is not a numeric vector. Your `eval()` statement returns a numeric vector just as `c(1, 2)` returns a numeric vector.